# Multiline into single line and output to a file

Tags: linux

I have a log file that writes multiline events. A event starts with `________________` and contains n number of lines detailing the event and ends after two newline characters.
Each time an event is written to the log file, I want to merge this multiline event into a single line and output the same to another file, which contains these events as single lines.

How can I do this in Linux?

Based on given suggestions, I came up with the code below.

```
tail -f audit.log | perl -pe 'chomp; s/^(_____)/\n$1/' | tr '\r' '\t' |
tr -d '________________________________________________________________________________' > audit_test1.log &
```

However, the file does not write anything generated by `audit.log` until I kill the background job. When I kill the job, the output is written to the `audit_test1.log`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Perl one-liner should do the job more or less. The `-pe` options mean to surround your script specified on the command line with a `while (<>) { YOUR_SCRIPT; print }` loop,
which reads the input file (or stdin) line by line, removes (chomps) the linefeed, and adds a linefeed before any line starting with `_____`.

Fixing a few minor issues like removing the first extra blank line, and adding spaces where the lines were joined, is left as an exercise to the OP. :-)

```
perl -pe 'chomp; s/^(_____)/\n$1/' file > another_file
```

To convert a logfile in the background (&) in real time (tail -f):

```
tail -f file | perl -pe 'chomp; s/^(_____)/\n$1/' > another_file &
```

Comment: Is it possible using bash shell commands? I would like to do this in realtime on the log file while the event is being written line by line... Maybe a combination of tail etc? write a new line into the second file when it receives a _________ and end the line and it encounters the newline characters twice in a row.

Comment: I modified the code but I it is not writing to file when using tail.

Comment: When Perl is writing to a file, it's buffering stdout. A lot. It collects a whole block (4K) data before the actual `write()` system call. To avoid it insert a `BEGIN { $| = 1 }` before `chomp`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is output buffering.  You have to make Perl run unbuffered.

http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/009 is one of many FAQs on this topic.

You need to [set `$| = 1` to make `STDOUT` unbuffered in Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).  However, you would also have to make `tr` unbuffered if you want to run two instances.  Since Perl can do everything `tr` can do, maybe do all the processing in Perl instead anyway.

```
tail -f audit.log | perl -pe 'BEGIN { $| = 1 } chomp; s/^(_____)/\n$1/;
    tr/\r/\t/; tr/_//d' > audit_test1.log &
```

The buffering problem should disappear if Perl is the last one in the pipeline, but I left it in just in case.

By the way, `tr` can only substitute all occurrences of each character you give it, so repeating `______` for 80 characters probably doesn't do what you expected.  If the intention is to remove runs of exactly that many characters but preserve others, you're better off doing `s/_{80}//` in Perl.

Comment: Thanks... I modified as below which worked :)

`tail -f audit.log | perl -pe 'BEGIN { $| = 1 } chomp;`
`s/^(_____)/\n$1/; s/_{80}//; s/\r/\t/' | audit_test1.log &`